# subprocess bad file on Python 3.6

Tags: python, subprocess

For any application that I may want to launch in my Ubuntu 18.04 and that depends on Python, I have the following error

```
[alexandre]~$ c
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.6.8 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
Exception information:

'list' object has no attribute 'read'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 90, in main
    if not cnf.advise(args[0], options.ignore_installed) and not options.no_failure_msg:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 353, in advise
    snaps, mispell_snaps = self.get_snaps(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 113, in get_snaps
    universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/run/__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
    process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/run/__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
    shlex.split(command),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 305, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The most iconic one is when I simply enter a command that does not exist. Command not found fails due to `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`.

It looks like subprocess should call run method, but it searches a wrong file that is in /usr/local

Thanks.

Comment: That's bizarre. Did you edit `subprocess.py`? Whatever the heck that `run` module is, its code shouldn't be getting called from `subprocess`.

Comment: No, I did not change `suprocess.py`. However, somewhat, there was a file called `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/subprocess.run.pth` that messed up. I cannot remember or figure out when it was created. I just remove it and everything went back to normal.